# Linux live kiosk

Tags: gratis, linux-distribution

I’m looking for a live Linux distribution to boot a machine in Kiosk mode.
(Firefox/Chrome + nVidia Driver + VLC)

These two are pretty good:

- http://webconverger.com
- http://porteus-kiosk.org

**HOWEVER** they are **paid / trial**.

I’m looking for a *gratis* and configurable distribution.

Comment: Archlinux + a light desktop like Openbox + Chromium ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[First hit](http://porteus-kiosk.org/) on a Google search for `free linux kiosk distro`:

```
Porteus Kiosk makes securing your public access computer easier than you  think. 
You no longer have to be a technical guru to customize, 
lock down and install your own kiosk. 
No need to worry about viruses, malware or users installing unwanted software.
```

---

See also http://tuxdiary.com/2014/11/05/linux-distros-for-kiosks/

- Porteus kiosk
  The mini distro Porteus has a dedicated mod to support kiosk mode. Provides options to customize as need on first boot.
- Instant WebKiosk
  Boots from USB key and browser only.
- Can Bike OS
  Puppy based live-CD OS with a webbrowser and little else.
- SanicKiosk
  Turn-key web kiosk designed for public libraries, city government, health clinics, and other institutions in need of public information stations. It is intended for easy installation and administration by users with minimal technical knowledge.
- Ubuntu Guest login
  Normal Ubuntu installation allows guest access from the login prompt. A perfect solution for kiosks. Login into guest mode with restricted permissions but non-restricted browser. Works from USB too.
- Scientific Linux 6 and CentOS 6
  Both the distros can be configured into kiosk-mode automatically by running this script.
- Webconverger (Unconfigured edition)
  Runs from USB, easy management console, highly secure, privacy conscious & fool-proof. No vendor lock-in, malware-free & firewall included. The Unconfigured offering is perfectly usable and free of cost.
- justbrowsing
  A bootable Linux “Live CD” that does not make any changes to the existing operating system on the computer. You can use the browser of your choice. Bundled webapps include a calculator, text editor, timer and more. Settings can be saved to a USB drive.

Comment: As you can check in their website (http://porteus-kiosk.org/automatic-updates.html) Porteus is not totally free.

Comment: Instant WebKiosk (http://www.binaryemotions.com/webkiosk-os/download.html) is freemium (extreme version). I'm looking for free, not freemium.